# Cursor Changes to ReqctQuill Editor

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, react-quill

I have another input boxn, now whenever I add text to that input, it automatically changes the cursor to focus on ReactQuill Editor.

Check the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-swanson-z80o2q?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please paste this into your editor.js.And Remove this <div className="textarea"></div>.

<ReactQuill
    theme="snow"
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={editorHtml}
    modules={modules}
    ref={quillRef}
    formats={formats}
    placeholder="Write Something"
  />
```

Comment: It works on removing div but I added div in order to have custom text Area.

Comment: For which purpose you want that div?